# Read-host stops after typing 0

Tags: windows, powershell

I wrote this script:

''

```
Write-Host "Enter new name, currently name: $env:COMPUTERNAME"
$NewCompName = Read-Host

$renamecomputer = $true
if ($NewCompName -eq "" -or $NewCompName -eq $env:COMPUTERNAME) {$NewCompName = $env:COMPUTERNAME; $renamecomputer = $false}

Write-Host "Choose OU [1-3] (default 1):
1. Open,
2. Limited,
3. IT"
$ou = Read-Host

$validou = $false
if ($ou -eq  "" -or $ou -eq "1") {$ou = "XYZ"; $validou = $true}
if ($ou -eq "2") {$ou = "OU=XYZ"; $validou = $true}
if ($ou -eq "3") {$ou = "OU=XYZ"; $validou = $true}

if($validou -eq $false) {Write-Host "Wrong OU, default 1"; $ou  = "XYZ"}

$domain = "SampleDomain"
$password = "SamplePass" | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force
$username = "$domain\domena"
$creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username,$password)

Write-Host "Adding $NewCompName to domain"

Add-Computer -DomainName XYZ -Credential $creds -OUPath $ou

Read-Host "Press Enter"

if($renamecomputer -eq $true)
{Rename-Computer -Newname $NewCompName -DomainCredential $creds}
Read-Host "Press Enter to restart computer"
Restart-Computer
```

''

When I try to rename computer to 'STK02212' the name changes to 'STK0', the read-host command stops every time after entering '0'. I tried to find a solution but found no such error on the internet. Do you have any idea?

Comment: There isn't a command `read-name` in the script? Did you forget to paste it, or did you mean `read-host`?

Comment: I meant read-host, my bad :)

Comment: Does `Get-PSReadLineKeyHandler | where key -eq 0` return any results?